# Сортировка массива с объектами js

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Здравствуйте, мне по API приходит массив с объектами, в каждом объекте есть ключ price. Нужно сделать фильтрацию по убыванию и возрастанию цены. Но с сервера иногда может приходить price пустой или равен 0, тогда нужно эти объекты показывать в самом низу, при любой сортировке по убыванию или возрастанию. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.
Вот код, который есть сейчас.
products - массив с объектами

---

```
const sortArray = (type) => {
 switch(type) {
  case 'cheap':
    return products.sort((objA, objB) => {
      return objA.price - objB.price;
    });

  case 'expensive':
    return products.sort((objA, objB) => {
      return objB.price - objA.price;
    });
}
```

};

Comment: а не могли бы вы поделиться кодом. У меня похожая задача стоит. Заранее благодарю. :)

Comment: @Nurilya это было давно, кода у меня нет того, на сколько я помню, я использовал то решение, что мне предложили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну сделайте функцию сортировки такую:

```
(objA, objB) => {
    var priceA = objA.price || 0;
    var priceB = objB.price || 0;
    return priceA - priceB;
}
```

В данном случае если у объекта нет `price`, то цена будет `0`. Можете поменять логику, и присваивать цене какое-то огромное значение, если нужно поместить объект с другой стороны списка. Как-то так

Comment: спасибо, работает, но будет ли считать такое решение верным, если присваивать цене какое-то огромное значение? Просто с нулем вроде все хорошо, а огромное значение как-то странно выглядит, опять же на каком огромном значении остановиться..

Comment: На [этом](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: Спасибо! Еще попробовал вместо огромного числа поставить Infinity. Такое решение допустимо?)

Comment: @nazarukroman нет, ибо `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY - Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY = NaN`